# Can SQL Developer SQL Tuning Advisor bind variables be null?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-tuning

In SQL Developer (v 4.1) when I try to run the SQL Tuning Advisor on a query with one or more bind variables, if I leave any of them null, the SQL Tuning Advisor doesn't show any info at all.  Is this a SQL Developer bug, or have I misunderstood something about null values, binding, and tuning?

Here is a simple example:

```
select * from dual where :p = 1;
```

Highlight the query and press Ctrl + F12, and you're prompted for the value of `p`.  Leave the "NULL" checkbox checked and click "Apply":

[image: Enter Binds for p]

The SQL Tuning Advisor seems to quit running immediately and displays no detail for the query:

[image: SQL Tuning Advisor showing empty Details]

Is this a SQL Developer bug, or have I misunderstood something about null values, binding, and tuning?

Comment: I can not reproduce the error with SQL Developer 17.2 and the 12c database.  I did notice some bugs associated with the SQL Tuning Advisor associated with binds with the 10g database (e.g. Bug 6854919).

Comment: Thanks @PatrickBacon.  I ran on a copy of 17.2 and it works correctly, so the bug has evidently been corrected.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from dual where nvl(:p,-1) = 1;
```

any null in WHERE clause makes all boolean algebra NULL (FALSE)